# Javascript function argument setting through DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a select element which I'm creating through javascript (DOM)

```
var cell_stock_id = row.insertCell(0);
var cell_stock_id_sel = document.createElement('select');
```

I have kept an onchange javascript function for this-

```
cell_stock_id_sel.setAttribute("onchange","populateOtherFields");
```

The function gets called when i change the selected option in select.

Is there a way I can pass an argument to this function "populateOtherFields" ?

I have a select box and a lot of text fields in a table row. I want to populate those rows based on the selection. I'm able to access the data which has to be inserted in those fields, but I don't know how to enter the data in those textfields for that row. I'm thinking of passing a unique number which will identify with the names of the elements in a row, and the javascript will parse that pattern in the names of the elements of the row.

```
 document.forms["0"].elements[i].name.indexOf("pattern").
```

So is there a way by which i can pass this "pattern", which is essentially the iteration (no. of rows, row number) number.

```
select__1, text__1, text2__1
select__2, text__2, text2__2
```

The '__1' , and the '__2' need to be passed. And they're not static patterns. Could be any number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `setAttribute` to set up event handlers, use direct assignment or (better) `addEventListener` / `attachEvent` and then you can create a function that will call your function with the desired arguments. (You could do that anyway, of course, but using `setAttribute` you'd either have to do it inline or create yet another global, named function.)

Direct assignment:

```
cell_stock_id_sel.onchange = function() {
    populateOtherFields(arguments, here);
};
```

Works on all browsers, but you can only have a single `change` handler on the element using this method (as with `setAttribute`).

`addEventListener`:

```
cell_stock_id_sel.addEventListener('change', function() {
    populateOtherFields(arguments, here);
}, false);
```

This is [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener), but it doesn't exist on older versions of IE.

`attachEvent`:

```
cell_stock_id_sel.attachEvent('onchange', function() {
    populateOtherFields(arguments, here);
});
```

This is IE-only (er, mostly, some browsers throw a bone to IE-only sites). It's Microsoft's pre-standard way of doing it. In IE8 and above in standards mode, you can use `addEventListener` instead.

Another advantage of **all** of these methods is that you don't have to have any global functions, whereas the `setAttribute` way, if you use a function name, that function has to be global. The global namespace on browsers is already *really* crowded, I always recommend avoiding adding to the clutter.

---

Because of the various vagaries between browsers, I tend to recommend using any decent JavaScript browser library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/library), or [any of several others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JavaScript_libraries). These smooth over differences like the `addEventListener` / `attachEvent` thing and also provide a **lot** of helpful utility functionality.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this-     `cell_stock_id_sel.addEventListener('change',function(){ populateOtherFields(5); },false); `. However, the function `populateOtherFields(arg) { alert(arg); }` gives "undefined" instead of "5". This is all there is to it, really. Is there some kind of formatting?

Comment: Ok This worked. I created a variable inside the function, assigned the value of the variable to it which i orginially wanted to pass, and the value is accessible at the function. many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
cell_stock_id_sel.addEventListener("onchange", function() {
    populateOtherField(arguments);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this-     `cell_stock_id_sel.addEventListener('change',function(){ populateOtherFields(5); },false); `. However, the function `populateOtherFields(arg) { alert(arg); }` gives "undefined" instead of "5". This is all there is to it, really. Is there some kind of formatting?

Comment: Ok This worked. I created a variable inside the function, assigned the value of the variable to it which i orginially wanted to pass, and the value is accessible at the function. many thanks.